# Spring batch local partition job running too slow

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch

I am reading 1.6millions records from mongodb and writing to oracle db. Here is my job configuration.

//Job config

```
@Bean
public Job dataImportForACollectionsJob() {
return jobBuilderFactory.get("dataImportForACollectionsJob")
            .start(importDataForACollectionMasterStep)
            .listener(listener)
            .build();
```

}

//Master step config

```
@Bean
public Step importDataForACollectionMasterStep() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("importDataForACollectionMasterStep")
            .partitioner(importDataForACollectionWorkerStep.getName(),partitionerForJobParam(null))
            .partitionHandler(importDataForACollectionPartitionHandler)
            .step(importDataForACollectionWorkerStep)
            .listener(stepListener())
            .build();
```

}

//partitioner config

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public Partitioner partitionerForJobParam(@Value("#{jobParameters['collectionName']}")String 
 collectionName) {
    MongoPartitioner partitioner = new MongoPartitioner();
    partitioner.setCollectionName(collectionName);
    return partitioner;
}
```

//worker step config

```
@Bean
public Step importDataForACollectionWorkerStep() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory.get("importDataForACollectionWorkerStep")
            .<Document, DataRecovery>chunk(10)
            .reader(mongoDbItemReader(null,null,null))
            .processor(batchItemProcessorFromJobParam(null))
            .writer(itemWriter())
            .build();
}
```

//reader config

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public MongoItemReader<Document> mongoDbItemReader(@Value("#{stepExecutionContext['gte']}") Long gte,
                                                   @Value("#{stepExecutionContext['lt']}") Long lt,
                                                   @Value("# 
    {stepExecutionContext['collectionName']}") String collectionName) {
    MongoItemReader<Document> mongoItemReader = new MongoItemReader<>();
    List<Object> parameterList=new ArrayList<Object>();
    parameterList.add(gte);
    parameterList.add(lt);
    mongoItemReader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
    mongoItemReader.setCollection(collectionName);
    mongoItemReader.setQuery("{id:{$gt:?0, $lte:?1}}");
    mongoItemReader.setParameterValues(parameterList);
    mongoItemReader.setTargetType(Document.class);
    mongoItemReader.setQuery(new Query().limit(5));
    mongoItemReader.setSort(new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>() {{
        put("_id", Sort.Direction.DESC);
    }});
    mongoItemReader.setPageSize(5);
    return mongoItemReader;
}
```

//writer config

```
@Bean
public JdbcBatchItemWriter<WR3DataRecovery> itemWriter() {
    JdbcBatchItemWriter<WR3DataRecovery> jdbcBatchItemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new 
    BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<DataRecovery>());
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setSql("INSERT INTO 
    TABLE(ID,APPID,AP,FY,OBJECT_NAME,OBJECT_SEQ_ID," 
    +"SCOPE_NAME,TEMPLATE_NAME,OBJECT_INFO,ACTIVE,IS_PRIMARY,CREATED_BY,CREATED_DATE,LAST_UPDATED_BY,LAST_UPDATED_DATE)" +
            " VALUES(ECORERPTMD_CORE.hibernate_sequence.nextval,:appId,:aP,:fY,:objectName,:objectSeqId,:scopeName,:templateName," +
            ":objectInfo,:active,:isPrimary,:createdBy,:createdDate,:lastUpdatedBy,:lastUpdatedDate)");
    jdbcBatchItemWriter.setDataSource(dataSource);
    return jdbcBatchItemWriter;
}
```

// partition handler config

```
@Bean
public PartitionHandler importDataForACollectionPartitionHandler() {
    return taskExecutorPartitionHandler(importDataForACollectionWorkerStep);
}


private TaskExecutorPartitionHandler taskExecutorPartitionHandler(Step step){
    TaskExecutorPartitionHandler retVal = new TaskExecutorPartitionHandler();
    retVal.setTaskExecutor(threadPoolTaskExecutor());
    retVal.setStep(step);
    retVal.setGridSize(10);
    return retVal;
}


private ThreadPoolTaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
    taskExecutor.setThreadNamePrefix("threadPoolTaskExecutor-");
    taskExecutor.afterPropertiesSet();
    return taskExecutor;
}
```

//partitioner logic

```
Long partitionCount = count/gridSize;
Long gte = 0L;
Long lt = 0L;

for(int j = 0; j < gridSize; j++) {
    if(j == gridSize-1) {
            lt = count;
    }else{
          lt += partitionCount;
    }
    result.put("partition"+j, createExecutionContext("partition"+j, 
    gte.toString(), lt.toString(),getCollectionName()));
        gte+= partitionCount;
}
```

//job repository config

```
@Configuration
public class JobMetaDataLocalConfig extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {
   @Override
   @Autowired
   public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
   }
 }
```

I am running in my local windows 10 machine. Below are my partition execution stats.

Step: [importDataForACollectionWorkerStep:partition8] executed in 21s965ms

Step: [importDataForACollectionWorkerStep:partition5] executed in 10s493ms

Step: [importDataForACollectionWorkerStep:partition2] executed in 2m7s236ms

Step: [importDataForACollectionWorkerStep:partition4] executed in 4m0s52ms

Step: [importDataForACollectionWorkerStep:partition7] executed in 18m36s676ms

**Step: [importDataForACollectionWorkerStep:partition6] executed in 15h48m39s976ms**

//Partition log

partition0 : {partition=partition0, lt=316, gte=0, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

partition1 : {partition=partition1, lt=632, gte=316, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

partition2 : {partition=partition2, lt=948, gte=632, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

partition3 : {partition=partition3, lt=1264, gte=948, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

partition4 : {partition=partition4, lt=1580, gte=1264, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

partition5 : {partition=partition5, lt=1896, gte=1580, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

partition6 : {partition=partition6, lt=2212, gte=1896, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

partition7 : {partition=partition7, lt=2528, gte=2212, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

partition8 : {partition=partition8, lt=2844, gte=2528, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

partition9 : {partition=partition9, lt=3162, gte=2844, collectionName=GenericDataDomain}

If you look above partition steps execution, the last step partition6 has taken 15hrs and remaining step partitions are still running. Why did step partition6 take 15hrs others took less time? What is wrong with below spring batch local partition job configuration?

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: Feel like it is not the problem of data partitioning but it is your batch job is actually running that slow.To isolate the problem , how about disable the partitioning , and just run a single thread spring job for the same data that is partitioned in partition6 , how long does it take?

Comment: Are you sure your partitioner is partitioning data in a uniform way? Can you output the result of your partitioning process? Something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54571457/5019386. Otherwise, please share how many items you have in each partition. Moreover, are you using the Map-based job repository? If yes, it could be the cause of the issue, see point `2. Poor Performance` here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/3780.

Comment: I have edited the post, added partitioned log output and job repository.

Comment: Ran job without partitioning, it is still taking longer time. it took almost 36hrs to export 500K records from mongo to oracle.

Comment: Point 2 says do not use map based job repository. As i am extending DefaultBatchConfigurer for local run which uses MapJobRepositoryFactoryBean in initialize method, you are saying do not extend the class DefaultBatchConfigurer for local run?

Answer (score 0):

Lot factors can contribute this delay and below points will help to identify the issue

1. Operating System windows. If you try in Linux you will see the real benchmark.
2. Try with single partition as mentioned by Ken to narrow down the delay.
3. CPU configurations of your windows and memory.
4. Any delay in read for selected partition.
5. Data source connection pool configuration.

If still not able to identify share the code in github we can verify with Mongo and Oracle.